# Why do pint Quantities display differently in QtConsole than in an iPython console and how do I change it?

Tags: ipython, qtconsole, pint

So, I use the `pint` units package and would like values displayed in the console to be standard fixed width font, not a 'rendered' display. I use Spyder IDE which uses QtConsole and displays either html or latex png. The following screen shots illustrate.

I don't want this:
[image: Jupyter QtConsole]

I want this:
[image: Terminal iPython]

Does anyone know how I can make QtConsole display as standard fixed width font?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution. It turns out there is a configuration setting that will turn off rich text in QtConsole. Adding the line

```
c.JupyterQtConsoleApp.plain = True
```

to the `jupyter_qtconsole_config.py` file located in `~/.jupyter` (on my Mac) solved the issue.